# VBA Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

The VBA code is running over Excel, I'm trying to insert 3 lines after a bookmark in Word, but I get the error message "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I run the code over Word and works perfectly, I don't know whats going on... Here is a part of the code:

```
If iCounter > 1 Then
   oDoc.Bookmarks("Entregables").Range.Select
   Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1 'Here is where I get the error
   Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

If running from Excel, and automating Word, The `Selection` property will be interpreted as an Excel object. Just qualify `Selection` with the document.ActiveWindow reference:

```
If iCounter > 1 Then
   oDoc.Bookmarks("Entregables").Range.Select
   oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1 'Here is where I get the error
   oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
End If
```